# Composing relation with identity yields original relation

Tags: reference-request, proof-verification, relations, quantifiers, quantifier-elimination

Let $\phi: F\rightarrow G$ be a relation and $id_F$ be the identity relation on $F$. Then $\phi\circ id_F = \phi$ .

*Attempted proof*:
$$\phi\ \circ id_F = \{(f,g)\in F\times G: \exists f_2\in F((f_1,f_2)\in id_F \ and \ (f_2, g)\in \phi)\}$$
$$= \{(f,g)\in F\times G: \exists f_2\in F((f_2, g)\in \phi)\}$$
$$= \{(f,g)\in F\times G: (f, g)\in \phi\}$$
$$= \phi \ . $$

In line 1, do we read "...such that there exists $f_2$ in $F$ such that *for some* $f_1$ in $F$..."?

And can "$(f_1,f_2)\in id_F$" be "eliminated" by the observation that it holds for all members of $F$, and so existentially quantifying it is useless?

Finally, is there any elementary reference for such quantifier elimination?

**Edit:** I should clarify the reference request; I'm sure I could find something by googling, but would I search for "quantifier elimination" or "quantifiers in set builder notation", etc. to learn about these kinds of problems?

Comment: $f_1$ is not bound.  Do you have a typo?  If you think no, where does $f_1$ come from?

Comment: That's the first part of my question. I think that if I'm defining a composition, it should be $\exists f_2\exists f_1\in F((f_1, f_2) \in id_F...)$?

Comment: Ah, okay.  If what you wrote, even with the extra existential quantification added, was the definition of relational composition, wouldn't that mean $f$ is being completely ignored?

Comment: Right, so $(f,g)\in F\times G$ should be $(f_1,g)\in F\times G$?

Comment: That would work, or, equivalently, you could just remove the subscript 1s.